# IE 8 ignore <br> or <br /> tag

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have something like this

[image]

These column's content(the middle box of each columns) will be generated from the server so I don't know how many lines they have. This design will repeat in many pages and some of these pages have less column so I need to add a class for the width of these columns.

Some columns have different style like the second column from the right - it has red header and a little margin from bottom.

I need to count all the possibilities for any type of data and this is my code:

```
    <ul class="col styleCol5">
                        <li class="col5">
                            <h2 class="col5Header colHeader"><span>خلاصه محصول</span></h2>
                            <div class="col5Content colContent">
                                <span><span class="red">1.</span> نیازمند یک وکیل و کارگزار متخصص و امین جهت سرمایه‌گذاری وجوه خود و بهره‌مندی از عواید حاصل از این سر‌مایه‌گذاری می‌باشید.</span>
                                <br>
                                <span><span class="red">2.</span> به دنبال سپرده‌گذاری در حالت‌های مختلف و شرایط متنوع هستید.</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col5More colMore">
                                <span><a href="javascript:void">بیشتر</a></span><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col5">
                            <h2 class="col5Header colHeader"><span>شرح کامل محصول</span></h2>
                            <div class="col5Content colContent">
                                <span class="red closedTitle">یک فرصت سرمایه گذاری بدون ریسک با بالاترین سود علی‌الحساب</span>
                                <span>سپرده‌سرمایه‌گذاری رویان مهر یکی از مجموعه سپرده‌های سرمایه‌گذاری مؤسسه مالی و اعتباری مهر است که ...</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col5More colMore">
                                <span><a href="javascript:void">بیشتر</a></span><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col5">
                            <h2 class="col5Header colHeader"><span>نرخ سود</span></h2>
                            <div class="col5Content colContent nerkh">
                                <span>مشاهده جدول مقاطع زمانی دریافت سود در سپرده رویان مهر...</span>
                                <span class="table"><a href="javascript:void(0)">جدول نرخ سود</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col5More colMore">
                                <span><a href="javascript:void">بیشتر</a></span><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col5">
                            <h2 class="col5Header colHeader"><span>محاسبات مالی</span></h2>
                            <div class="col5Content colContent mali">
                                <span>نرم افزار محاسبه سود سرمایه. نرم افزار محاسبه سود سرمایه.</span>
                                <span class="softwareMali"><a href="javascript:void(0)">مشاهده نرم افزار</a></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col5More colMore">
                                <span><a href="javascript:void">بیشتر</a></span><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>

                        <li class="col5">
                            <h2 class="col5Header colHeader"><span>نکات مهم</span></h2>
                            <div class="col5Content colContent">
                                <span>سپرده سرمایه‌گذاری سما یکی از مجموعه سپرده‌های سرمایه‌گذاری مؤسسه مالی و اعتبار مؤسسه مالییهای سرمایه‌گذاری مؤسسه ما مهر است که سپرده‌گذار با افتتاح حساب سرمایه‌گذاری به مؤسسه وکالت عام می‌دهد تا سرمایه ...</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col5More colMore">
                                <span><a href="javascript:void">بیشتر</a></span><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>
                            </div>
                        </li>



                    </ul

>
```

With JQUERY I add some padding or margins to necessary classes:

```
$("span.closedTitle").after("<br><br>");

    $(".colContent.nerkh > span, .colContent.mali > span").prepend("<br>");
    $(".colContent.nerkh span.table, .colContent.mali span.softwareMali").prepend("<br><br><br>");
```

I do it with `BR` tag because I need the space to seem like line spaces and I don't want to add fixed height so I use `BR` tag.

It works except IE 8, it ignores the `BR` tag.

What should I do ?
Thanks.

Comment: js fiddle of what? IE 8 ?!

Comment: Your code so i can run it on ie8.

Comment: liveweave.com works under IE8, editing and show

Comment: If you need to add extra spacing, it's better to use CSS.  Margins, padding, line-height, etc.

Comment: the problem is BR tag with JQUERY , 

I Know my code is correct, IE 8 doesnt insert Br tag to my classes

what should i do for it ?

Comment: see my answer. <br> is not suppose to stand in an inline-block level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's a good idea to set span as inline-block elements and turn br into 
`padding-bottom:1.2em` , for one line if `line-height` is `1.2em`;

Comment: You need first to set font-size and line-height. then multiplicate line-height value as padding top or bottom to add lines space you need

Comment: what if i dont change it to inline-block ?

Comment: padding won't be applyied, inline is not suppose to, make it display block to be simple , or best, use <p> with margin reset to 0. :)

Comment: fiddle missing maybe ? ... no idea